# Simple OpenGL implementatione

Tags: flash, opengl, alchemy

I work on port of some casual games to Flash.
They are based on OpenGL. Used OpenGL version is 1.x mostly. Game engine relies is 2D. It bases on OpenGL textures and simplest glBegin/glTexCoord/glVertex/glEnd. Blending and tiling is used too.

The question.
I do not want to reinvent OpenGL again. Please tell - maybe you know simple open source OpenGL C/C++ implementation? I try to use Alchemy so C/C++ are welcome :)
I found already Mesa3d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) would be one obvious possibility. About the only other of which I'm aware would be [SGI's Sample Implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100221203727/http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/) (aka, *The S.I.*). Although intended as an open-source effort, the S.I. hasn't been updated (at least to my knowledge) in a long time, whereas there is ongoing development of Mesa3d.