# Where can I download Source Code Of "OpenGL"?

Tags: open-source, opengl

Where can I download Source Code Of "OpenGL" ?

Comment: OpenGL is a standard API, not a piece of software. You will need to look for the source code of a specific OpenGL implementation.

Comment: OpenGL itself is just a specification, not an implementation.  You are most likely looking for what Eric posted as an answer, the source to a true implementation of the OpenGL spec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple OpenGL implementatione](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086901/simple-opengl-implementatione)

Comment: @TylerMcHenry Who implements OpenGL?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/rswinkle/PortableGL

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to see how a rasterizer (the thing that displays polygons on the screen) is done in software, follow Eric's suggestion and check out mesa3d or google "rasterizer".

If you want to see how a rasterizer is done on hardware, I'm afraid the only thing you can have access to is [a photo of a GPU die](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912035505/http://images.bit-tech.net/content_images/2008/06/nvidia-geforce-gtx-280-architecture-review/gt200.jpg).

If you want to see how a 3D engine is done, take a look at Ogre, Irrlicht or any other.

If you want to know what happens under the hood when you call glDrawArray on a geForce, you can't. The drivers are proprietary. They more or less forward the call to the graphic card, but it's such a simplification... for instance, a typical DirectX call takes more than 10000 cpu instructions.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that your link is broken.

Comment: Who is *Eric*?!