# Using Adobe Alchemy to get the OpenGL image from c++ code to flash app

Tags: flash, opengl, swc, alchemy, gldrawpixels

I have C++ application that use OpenGL. Need to convert this app to flash app. Is it possible to do this with Adobe Alchemy? Is it will be possible to get from that swc current image (for example, with glDrawPixels) and print it on screen

Answer (score 1):

There's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086901/simple-opengl-implementatione) here on SO already, seems that [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) could be a good starting point, but it's going to be a lot of work :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  You can't just link to some already-compiled OpenGL lib-- you'd have to compile it from source.  Most likely it wouldn't compile as it would have calls into OS-specific hardware acceleration.

The long answer is that you could possibly refactor an OpenGL library so that it renders using Flash's hardware-acceleration APIs.  Would be pretty cool, actually.  But, as dain said, "it's going to be a lot of work".